# Handling events between classes

Tags: java, swing, class, events, communication

I have a main class with an Editor class (with a JTextPane) and a Toolbar class (with a JList and a Jbutton, I don't want to use JToolBar). These two classes are composed by many components and I would like not to mix them into the same class. I want the editor and the toolbar to communicate.
Let's say I write "Hello" in the toolbar and then click on Submit. I want the text pane to show me "Hello".
I build the classes this way:

```java
public class Main{
    public MainGUI(){
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents(){
        JFrame mainframe=new JFrame("Main Frame");
        Editor editor=new Editor();
        Toolbar toolbar=new Toolbar();
        mainframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainframe.getContentPane().add(editor, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainframe.getContentPane().add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class Editor extends JPanel{
    public Editor(){
        super();
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents(){
        JTextPane textpane=new JTextPane();

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(textpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

public class Toolbar extends JPanel{
    public Toolbar(){
        super();
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents(){
        JTextField textfield=new JTextField();
        JButton submitbutton=new JButton("Submit");

        this.setLayout(newFlowLayout());
        this.add(textfield);
        this.add(submitbutton);
    }
}
```

How should I implement the event handling betweenthe Toolbar and the Editor?

Comment: Make a separate Class for Event Handling and pass the references of these two Classes to that Class and simply do your trick for the magic to begin :-) Though for that you need to make your fields **Instance Fields**, instead of them being Local to the function alone. Since the scope of the things you want to access outside is limited to the `initComponents()` method alone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create an interface `ValueSubmittedListener`

```
interface ValueSubmittedListener {
    public void onSubmitted(String value);
}
```

and have `Editor` implements it.

```
class Editor implements ValueSubmittedListener{

    ...

    public void onSubmitted(String value) {
        // add text to JTextPane.
    }
}
```

Then have `Toolbar` provide methods

```
class Toolbar {

    private List<ValueSubmittedListener> listeners = new ArrayList<ValueSubmittedListener>();


    public void addListener(ValueSubmittedListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    private void notifyListeners() {
        for (ValueSubmittedListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onSubmitted(textfield.getText());
        }
    }

}
```

Then everytime you need to send new value to Editor (i.e: in `submitButton`'s `ActionListener`), just invoke the method `notifyListeners`.

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention that in the `initComponents` of `Main`, you have to register `Editor` to `Toolbar`:

```
private void initComponents() {
   JFrame mainframe = new JFrame("Main Frame");
   Editor editor = new Editor();
   Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
   toolbar.addListener(editor); // register listener
   ...
}
```

Comment: Got it. I'll try :-) What about using the Java's ActionListener instead of writing a new one? Could I experience some problems with it?

Comment: The idea of my answer is to use the Event Handling of Swing. You could reuse the `ActionListener` as well.

Comment: This works great for me and it is a good programming lesson as well. Thank you :-)

Comment: You're welcome! This is just a simple implementation of [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). You could learn more design patterns [here](http://www.javaworld.com/columns/jw-java-design-patterns-index.html)

Answer (score 2):

The key principal is to pass references as appropriate so that each object can access the objects it needs.

For example, if your "submit" means to append the text in the text field (that you have in your toolbar) to the editor's text pane, then you could do the following:

```java
public class Main{
    public MainGUI(){
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents(){
        JFrame mainframe=new JFrame("Main Frame");
        Editor editor=new Editor();
        Toolbar toolbar=new Toolbar(editor);
        mainframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainframe.getContentPane().add(editor, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainframe.getContentPane().add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}

private final JTextPane textpane=new JTextPane();
public class Editor extends JPanel{
    public Editor(){
        super();
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents(){
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(textpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void appendText(final String text) {
        this.textpane.setText( this.textpane.getText()+text );
    }
}

public class Toolbar extends JPanel{
    private final Editor editor;
    public Toolbar(final Editor editor){
        super();
        this.editor = editor;
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents(){
        final JTextField textfield=new JTextField();
        JButton submitbutton=new JButton("Submit");
        submitbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event) {
                editor.appendText( textfield.getText() );
            }
            });

        this.setLayout(newFlowLayout());
        this.add(textfield);
        this.add(submitbutton);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work but in this case my Toolbar class should be composed by an Editor. I'm not about to bind these classes together this strong.

Comment: Okay.  There are many ways you can arrange the interfaces and the interaction between the two.  This is just one way, starting with the code you posted.  I recommend studying the various documented [Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) for well recognized ideas on organization of software.